# awk read from file to array

Tags: bash, awk

I got file with some data like this :

```
1:Bob A  :Tester
2:John B :Assembler
```

I use awk on this file with this code :

```
BEGIN{
print"ABC Computing"    
FS = ":"
}

# $1 -  id , $2 - name, $3 - position.
NF == 3{
nameArray[$1]+=$2 
}

END{
for (x in nameArray )
{print  x,  nameArray[x]}
}
```

And all I get on the output is :

```
ABC Computing
1 0
2 0
3 0
4 0
5 0
6 0
7 0
8 0
```

I need something like this :

```
1 Bob A 
2 John B
```

I cant get string part to store in array.

Thank you

Comment: the code you tried has `print"ABC Computing"` .. why does it not reflect in expected output? based on sample input and output, does your problem statement reduce to getting first two columns from each line with `:` as delimiter and changing to space in output?

Comment: If I change the `+=` to just an `=` it works as expected.

Comment: What's your aim here? You could just remove the last field for your output.

Comment: Thank you guys, I understand my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line `nameArray[$1]+=$2` in your code attemts to add `0` to 2nd field value(string), which gives `0` every time

It should be as follows:

```
awk -F':' 'BEGIN{print "ABC Computing"}NF==3{a[$1]=$2}END{for(i in a) print i,a[i]}' file
```

The output:

```
ABC Computing
1 Bob A  
2 John B
```

Comment: It works! thanks, I don't understand where was my mistake?